# How should I implement lazy loading for my images in react?

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading

I'm trying to add lazy loading to my react application as I have over 200 images that I don't need on the initial load. If I lazy load the images, does this mean, they won't be loaded until they're needed on the screen?

I'm currently importing 4 groups of about 50 images into .js files and then adding them to objects so they can be dynamically used in my components. It looks like this...

```
// SportImages.js file
import Football from './images/football.png
import Cricket from './images/cricket.png
import Soccer from './images/soccer.png
... // another 50 or so imports

export default {
  Football,
  Cricket,
  Soccer,
  ... // another 50 or so files
}

// and then in my component
cards.map(x => {
  return (
    <img src={SportImages[x.image_ref]} />
  )
})
```

So my question is, should I be using lazy loading in the component file or in the main images file if I want to lazy load every image?

Comment: Have you.looked at react-lazyload npm package? It supports lazy loading of images out of the box. You can find documentation and examples here - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-lazyload

Comment: So I should lazy load them in the component? and will this defer the loading of all images until they're needed?

Comment: Yes I think so. I have not tried it personally but that is what the documentation says.

Answer (score 28):

You can add the [`loading`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/Lazy_loading#loading_attribute) attribute to your image element to lazy-load the images. A complete explainer guide on this attribute can be found on [web.dev](https://web.dev/articles/browser-level-image-lazy-loading).

In your case it would probably look as follows:

```
cards.map(card => (
  <img src={SportImages[card.image_ref]} loading="lazy" />
))
```

You should also make sure to specify the [`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-width) and [`height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-height) attributes so the browser can place the element on the page with the correct dimensions.

Comment: `loading=lazy` is currently not supported on Safari on IOS: https://caniuse.com/?search=loading

Comment: Worst case scenario it will load the images immediately, but this won't break any existing functionality.

Comment: That's right. However, it affects the UX for Safari users due to possible unnecessary loading of images.

Comment: Along with `loading="lazy"`, you also need to add dimensions either via `<img style="width: 1rem, height: 1rem" />` or `<img width="1rem" height="1rem" />`

Comment: Lazy loading is now supported in Safari as well https://webkit.org/blog/12445/new-webkit-features-in-safari-15-4/

Comment: This works on most browsers except Firefox. According to [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/?search=lazyloadin), this attribute is partially supported in Firefox.

Comment: It's partially supported in Firefox as it only supports images. Since this question is about images it's 100% supported for this use-case.

Answer (score 4):

As of 2023, all major browsers support the `loading="lazy"` attribute on the `img` tag ([caniuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=lazyloading)), which makes it the easiest way to implement lazy loading of images.

However, because of a [bug in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1647077), in order to make it work in Firefox, **the `loading` attribute must be placed before the `src` attribute.**

So, to paraphrase the answer of Jon Koops, until the bug in Firefox is resolved, this is the example that will work across Firefox, Chrome and Safari:

```
cards.map(card => (
  <img loading="lazy" src={SportImages[card.image_ref]} />
))
```

If you were to place `loading="lazy"` after the `src` attribute, the lazy loading works in Chrome, but not in Firefox.

Comment: It is work now in Firefox Version 112 even the loading attribute is placed after the src attribute.

Comment: I'm using Firefox ESR 115.7, and `loading="lazy"`  works only in this order. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library called **react-lazy-load-image-component**
Import the LazyLoadImage component then use it the render you images

```
cards.map(card => (
     <LazyLoadImage src={SportImages[card.image_ref]} {...props}/>
  ))
```

You can also add an effect when lazy loading the images. You can check the documentation of the library here
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-lazy-load-image-component

Answer (score 0):

`loading='lazy'` attribute **Safari not supported**

```html
<img loading=lazy src="image.jpg" />
```

Try this package:

```js
npm i react-lazy-load-image-component
```

Example:

```js
import React from 'react';

import { LazyLoadImage, trackWindowScroll } from 'react-lazy-load-image-component';

const Gallery = ({ images, scrollPosition }) => (
  <div>
    {images.map((image) =>
        <LazyLoadImage  scrollPosition={scrollPosition}
            width="100%"
            height="auto"
            src={image.url} />
    )}
  </div>
);
 
export default trackWindowScroll(Gallery);
```