# Optimize Performance of images in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance

I have a question regarding the performance of different types of images (like SVG, PNG, JPEG
) we render in UI.
Which Type is Best to render and the efficient way to implement it.
How can we Best implement it that it takes less time?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69054825/how-should-i-implement-lazy-loading-for-my-images-in-react

Answer (score 1):

You can use a library like [lazysizes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lazysizes), or you can use the `loading="lazy"` attribute which has now a [promising support](https://caniuse.com/loading-lazy-attr)

If you are using framework like Next.js, it has [built-in support for lazy loading images by `default` and much more](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image)

For a detailed insight, you may read this awesome article:

[Lazy Loading images](https://web.dev/lazy-loading-images/)

Comment: it doesn't answer my all question. Like I have image available in .svg format & also in .png format....then which one I should prefer to use?

Comment: For complex images, `svg` is not desirable, since it will have very large sizes. `svg` is preferred in small images, like logos & icons